# Linking PBC Library on iOS

Tags: ios, c, xcode, cryptography, gmp

I'm trying to integrate the [PBC library](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc) in my iOS project. The dependence of [GMP library](https://gmplib.org) is fixed. Did someone successfully installed pbc on iOS?

thanks!

Comment: Have you managed to get it to work? I need the same.

Comment: hello. no, i have used a mac os project.